# distinguish overlapped polyline in leaflet in zoom label 5km

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have 3 markers **A**, **B**, **C** where the distance between 2 markers **A**, **B** is only 12 meter and the last marker **C** is too far about (1200 km) from Marker **A** and **B**, when i draw polyline between them, I am getting single line between Marker **A** to **C** and **B** to **C** lines get overlapped at zoom level 5 km, How could i distinguish these 2 lines at Zoom level 5km in leaflet Map API?
below is my code used to implement the same.

```
var markerGroup = []

var A_LatLngObj = L.latLng(25.168595184684936, 75.84935768356826)
var B_LatLngObj = L.latLng(25.168532184684936, 75.84931268356826)
var C_LatLngObj = L.latLng(23.18376518685702, 77.45881298879502)

var marker_A = L.photoMarker(A_LatLngObj, {
                src: nodeMarkerSrc,
                size: [40, 40]
            });

var marker_B = L.photoMarker(B_LatLngObj, {
                src: nodeMarkerSrc,
                size: [40, 40]
            });

var marker_B = L.photoMarker(C_LatLngObj, {
                src: nodeMarkerSrc,
                size: [40, 40]
            });

markerGroup.push(marker_A);
markerGroup.push(marker_B);
markerGroup.push(marker_C);

var customPolyline = L.Polyline.extend({options: {data:''}});
var linkObj_AtoC = new customPolyline([A_LatLngObj, C_LatLngObj], {
                    data: linkData,
                    color: utilizationColor,
                    type: 'line',
                    fillColor: '#00a924',
                    fillOpacity: 1,
                    opacity: 10,
                    weight: 2,
                    clickable: true
                });


var linkObj_BtoC = new customPolyline([B_LatLngObj, C_LatLngObj], {
                    data: linkData,
                    color: utilizationColor,
                    type: 'line',
                    fillColor: '#00a924',
                    fillOpacity: 1,
                    opacity: 10,
                    weight: 2,
                    clickable: true
                });

markerGroup.push(linkObj_AtoC);
markerGroup.push(linkObj_BtoC);

map.addLayer(L.layerGroup(markerGroup));
```

Comment: Do you want so see a spread between the lines on each zoomlevel ? Or is it a possibility for you to hightlight the wanted line ?

Comment: yes Manuel, and i want to highlight lines on hover but currently only last line  object gets highlighted.

Comment: You would probably be interested in that post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/how-to-add-an-offset-to-a-geojson-layer-in-leaflet/201991#201991